# Understand CreateDatabaseIfNotExists

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Say we have two domain classes.

```
public class Blog 
{ 
    public int BlogId { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
} 

public class Post 
{ 
    public int PostId { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string Content { get; set; } 

    public int BlogId { get; set; } 
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; } 
}
```

Now let's create a Context.

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
}

    public BloggingContext () : base("Blogging")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<BloggingContext >(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BloggingContext>());
    }
```

Also in this class, we want to add some test data to verify it.

```
    public void AddBlog(params)
    {
        using (BloggingContext db = new BloggingContext ())
        {
            var t = new Blog { Name =name };
            db.Blogs.Add(t);
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
```

Then to test it, we create a unit test project.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        BloggingContext bloging= new BloggingContext ();

        List<Post> post = new List<Post>();
        Post objPost = new Post();
        objPost.Post = "some";
        objPost.OtherFields = "test"; 
        // etc;
        post.Add(objPost); 
        bloging.AddBlog("MyBlog",post);
```

To run the test, I found the code went to the constructor of BloggingContext class first, thus `Database.SetInitializer...` was executed.

Then when

> using (BloggingContext db = new BloggingContext ())

It called the constructor again, I am not sure whether it is ok.

Comment: why did you delete http://stackoverflow.com/q/23182734/6309? It could have help others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the constructor as many times you like

```
Database.SetInitializer<BloggingContext >(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BloggingContext>());
```

The `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` just does a DB check that if it really exists or not, if not it does create it, else it skips the database creation part !

Answer (score 0):

Name of the strategy does not really make sense.
Actually, what the CreateDatabaseIfNotExists strategy does is:

1. check if the database with the specified name exist or not, if not
   it'll create a new database
2. if the database with the specified name already exists, and if
   there's no tables/procs found in the db at all, it means the db is
   in "fresh new" status, then the strategy will also generate the db
   structure and insert seed data
3. If the database with the specified name already exists and there's
   some table / procs in the db then it will do nothing